# Amazon S3 for django in production

Tags: django, django-storage

I am using django-s3-folder-storage for my static and media files storage. I followed all the instructions mentioned in the documentation, but still I am not able to serve my static files. I am able to serve my user uploaded files, but the static files are not displayed on the website even after running collectstatic command, which copied the files to the bucket. I haven't created any CNAME records in my domain (not sure whether this makes any difference as I am able to see user uploaded images).

My settings file:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = "media"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.StaticStorage'
STATIC_S3_PATH = "static"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = # omitted
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = # omitted
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = # omitted

MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % DEFAULT_S3_PATH
MEDIA_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_ROOT = "/%s/" % STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       root('static'),
)
```

And my project directory:

```
website_name
    static
    website_name
      settings.py
```

Comment: I am using s3fox and for some reason i can not check whether the files are getting to bucket or not after collectstatic. i have posted another question here regarding that here. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747933/amazon-s3-problems-with-s3fox).    i am not able to access them with their direct URL as well ? I haven't setup any CNAME record point to s3.amazon.com ? Do i need to setup to access the static files ?

Comment: Try logging into S3 through Amazon's web interface and check the bucket's contents that way. Also, could you add your Django version, MEDIA_URL, and STATIC_URL settings to the question? (If you haven't changed your _URL settings to a new domain name, then no, your CNAME is not a problem yet.)

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question with my settings. And also i am able to see the bucket when i login using amazon user interface and i can see all my static files as well.

Comment: Hi, I have the bucket name specified in my settings and it exists on the amazon s3 as well. I am able to serve user uploaded files. it is only the static files which i am having problem with. When i inspect the elements in browser, the path to the static images is like i mentioned in my edit2. Could you let me know whether i need to add bucketname before s3.amazonaws.com etc starts as in my edit 2?

Comment: Hi, it is working now after changing the static url. i have updated my  question as well with edit.

Comment: I've added some thoughts on why you might be running into this problem as an answer, in case anyone else runs into this same issue. Could you move any relevant information from your comments into your question, and delete the comments that are no longer useful? You can also accept your own answer to show others that it's the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the STATIC_URL to like below and it is working fine now.

STATIC_URL = '//bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'

But MEDIA_URL is like mentioned in the documentation itself and MEDIA_URL works fine. It is only STATIC_URL which needs modifying.

Looks like the documentation is wrong.

Comment: I think it's not that the documentation is outright *wrong*, but that it just doesn't account for some aspect of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Generally S3 can use either the subdomain or subfolder path format. The default for `django-storages`, which is used by this particular storage, is subdomain. So it's interesting that changing to subfolder solved the problem. The OP mentions using the European region in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747933/amazon-s3-problems-with-s3fox), and I suspect the root problem here has to do with the endpoint being used, or one of S3/S3BotoStorage's region-affecting configuration settings (e.g. `AWS_CALLING_FORMAT`).