# Amazon S3 problems with S3fox

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created an Amazon S3 account and trying to upload some files with S3fox add-on.
I have added S3fox and logged in with my accesskey and secure id credentials.

Now, i created a bucket by right clicking and selecting create a directory and selected the option to put the bucket in europe. Now when i try to drill down into my folder, i keep getting an error message saying "Error connecting! -  Temporary Redirect". And also i can not transfer any files.

but if i create the bucket without selecting the option to put it into europe, then i am able to drill down into the bucket.

I would like my bucket to be in europe as i am from UK. Please suggest what i am missing and how can i resolve this issue?

Thanks
Sreekanth

Comment: This has been resolved automatically after few hours. The error is not happening any more. Probably just because the account is new, the data is not propagated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem - it still doesn't work after an hour. To save waiting I've installed Cloudberry (freeware for Windows), which seems to be a better alternative anyway (it looks more user-friendly and has more options): http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx